# how to gzip-compress large Ajax responses (HTML only) in Coldfusion?

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion, compression, gzip

I'm running `Coldfusion8` and `jquery/jquery-mobile` on the front-end.

I'm playing around with an Ajax powered search engine trying to find the best tradeoff between data-volume and client-side processing time.

Currently my AJAX search returns 40k of (JQM-enhanced markup), which avoids any client-side enhancement. This way I'm getting by without the page stalling for about 2-3 seconds, while JQM enhances all elements in the search results.

What I'm curious is whether I can `gzip Ajax responses` sent from Coldfusion. If I check the header of my search right now, I'm having this:

```
    RESPONSE-header
    Connection  Keep-Alive
    Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8
    Date    Sat, 01 Sep 2012 08:47:07 GMT
    Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=95
    Server  Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.21 ...
    Transfer-Encoding   chunked

    REQUEST-header
    Accept  */*
    Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
    Accept-Language de-de,de;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
    Connection  keep-alive
    Cookie  CFID=   ; CFTOKEN=   ; resolution=1143
    Host    www.host.com
    Referer http://www.host.com/dev/users/index.cfm
```

So, my request would accept `gzip, deflate`, but I'm getting back `chunked`.

I'm generating the AJAX response in a `cfsavecontent` (called compressedHTML) and run this to eliminate whitespace

```
<cfrscipt>
compressedHTML = reReplace(renderedResults, "\>\s+\<", "> <", "ALL");    
compressedHTML = reReplace(compressedHTML, "\s{2,}", chr(13), "ALL");
compressedHTML = reReplace(compressedHTML, "\s{2,}", chr(09), "ALL");
</cfscript>
```

before sending the compressedHTML in a response object like this:

```
 {"SUCCESS":true,"DATA":  compressedHTML  }
```

**Question**
If I know I'm sending back `HTML` in my data object via Ajax, is there a way to `gzip` the response server-side before returning it vs sending `chunked`? If this is at all possible? If so, can I do this inside my response object or would I have to send back "pure" HTML?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Found [this](http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2010/9/24/coldfusion-IIS7-Compression-Issue) on setting a 'web.config' for dynamic compression - doesn't seem to work

**EDIT2**: 
Found [thi](http://cfspaghetti.blogspot.de/2007/07/how-to-gzip-compress-coldfusion-8.html) snippet and am playing with it, although I'm not sure this will work.

```
<cfscript>
compressedHTML = reReplace(renderedResults, "\>\s+\<", "> <", "ALL");
compressedHTML = reReplace(compressedHTML, "\s{2,}", chr(13), "ALL");
compressedHTML = reReplace(compressedHTML, "\s{2,}", chr(09), "ALL");

if ( cgi.HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING contains "gzip" AND not showRaw ){
    cfheader name="Content-Encoding" value="gzip";

    bos = createObject("java","java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream").init();
    gzipStream = createObject("java","java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream");
    gzipStream.init(bos);
    gzipStream.write(compressedHTML.getBytes("utf-8"));
    gzipStream.close();
    bos.flush();
    bos.close();
    encoder = createObject("java","sun.misc.
    outStr= encoder.encode(bos.toByteArray());

    compressedHTML = toString(bos.toByteArray());
    } 
</cfscript>
```

Probably need to try this on the `response object` and not the `compressedTHML` variable

Comment: The response encoding is get in the `Content-Encoding` header field, not `Transfer-Encoding` header field. Your remark of `chunked` being returned is irrelevant

Comment: ok. Thanks. It's really the first time I'm looking at headers in detail...

Comment: check if this is of any help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559545/how-do-i-enable-gzip-compression-on-a-coldfusion-at-the-directory-level

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. Got it to work.

I'm using [this](http://cflib.org/udf/gzip#examples) from the CFLib like so:

```
<cfscript>
    // remove whitespace
    compressedHTML = reReplace(renderedResults, "\>\s+\<", "> <", "ALL");
    compressedHTML = reReplace(compressedHTML, "\s{2,}", chr(13), "ALL");
    compressedHTML = reReplace(compressedHTML, "\s{2,}", chr(09), "ALL");
    // gzip
    compressedHTML = gzip(compressedHTML);
</cfscript>
<!--- modify header --->
<cfheader name="Content-Encoding" value="gzip">
<cfheader name="Content-Length" value="#len(compressedHTML)#" >
<!--- return cfcontent with reset="no", so I'm not disrupting the Ajax request --->
<cfcontent reset="no" variable="#compressedHTML#" />
<cfreturn  />
```

You also need to make sure to set the return variables for the function which contains the above to `binary` and the Ajax request must use `returntype="html"`. At least that's how I got it to work.

Seems to work nice and my Ajax requests went from 50-60k enhanced markup down to 1-2k. Nice on mobile :-)

**EDIT**:
If you are having problems with special characters not being displayed correctly, try setting

```
 <cfheader name="Content-Type" value="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

before returning `cfcontent`. I don't know if this is better than `UTF-8`, but it work for German `äöüß`, which I was mising in my Ajax response.

Comment: UTF-8 is usually the right choice. I suspect the problem lies with the [`text.getBytes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) call inside gzip(). If you do not specify a charset, the jvm default is assumed. Change it to `text.getBytes("UTF-8")` and it should work fine with `charset=UTF-8`.

Comment: Note, `UTF-8` is usually *not* the default charset. So [`getBytes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28%29) and `getBytes("UTF-8")` would return very different results.